# User experience with map kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

Is it true that annotations in MapKit Framework are loaded lazily? By logging I found out that the viewForAnnotation is called at the start of loading Map itself.

Also I wish to load only those annotations which are visible in the map interface, remove them whenever they are off pan. How can I achieve this?

My final question is regarding the degradation of performance with number of annotations. I currently have around 10,000 annotations to be added to map. So how good is lazy loading for me? And is the Map View overloaded by these many annotations and hence will not be able to provide good user experience? Everything seems fine on the simulator, how will this matter on a real iPhone?

Comment: I've had *terrible* performance with many fewer than 10,000 annotations (I seem to remember having problems with even 1000 simple MKCircles).

Answer (score 1):

The way I look at it .... I would not load all the 10,000 annotations at once. The user will be in a specific position at any given point of time. I would load all the venues / annotations in and around that area so only relevant data is displayed to the user. When the user scrolls to some other part in the map ... I would then fetch the locations data / info for that specific point on the map and then load it instead of loading the whole thing. (i.e. all 10000 annotations).

Google Maps also does the same thing. It only loads relevant data i.e. data / locations / annotations which are in and around the area of the user. If the user scrolls or browses to another location, one can load the annotations which are in and around that area. So the whole process will be lighter and less worrisome.

Please take a CLOSER look at Google Maps.